# File validator always return error even the file type is correct - NestJS

Tags: node.js, nestjs, multer, nest

I'm working on NestJS. I want to upload image files through the API. I added the validator in the API but it is not working. Here is my code,

```
@Post('upload')
@UseInterceptors(
    FilesInterceptor('files', 3, {
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: './uploads/',
      }),
    }),
  )
uploadFile(
    @UploadedFiles(
        new ParseFilePipeBuilder()
        .addFileTypeValidator({
            fileType: 'jpg'
        })
        .addFileTypeValidator({
            fileType: 'png'
        })
        .addFileTypeValidator({
            fileType: 'jpeg'
        })
        .addMaxSizeValidator({
          maxSize: 10000
        })
        .build({
            errorHttpStatusCode: HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY
        })
    ) files: Array<Express.Multer.File>
) {
  console.log(files);
}
```

When I test it. I got error like this

[image]

Really thanks for every helps.

Answer (score 0):

The [FileTypeValidator](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/pipes/file/file-type.validator.ts) is not a "one-of" validator, it's an "exact-match" validator. You'd need to create your own file type validator to be able to check that the file type is one of the provided ones.

Answer (score -1):

try this
`.addFileTypeValidator({ fileType: /(jpg|jpeg|png)$/, })`